# How to add multiple icons for an input in semantic ui

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm using semantic ui to build a form input. I know how to put an icon with an input together. However I hope to put two icons with an input on left side and right side. Does anyone knows if it's possible? Thanks!

```html
<div class="ui left icon right action input">
    <i class="email icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="type...">
    <i class="check icon">
    <button class="ui basic button">submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want.

```
<div class="ui left icon right action input">
    <i class="email icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="type...">
    <button class="ui basic labeled icon button"><i class="check icon">submit</button>
</div>
```